# Hive end of the last month

Tags: variables, hive

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_month
PARTITION (dt= LAST_DAY('${CURRENT_DATE}'))
SELECT '${CURRENT_DATE}', LAST_DAY('${CURRENT_DATE}');
```

Current date is first day of the month.  I want to achieve something like above. It is not working. This will be HiveQL used in oozie.

Comment: Not working, sure. Take a couple of weeks to read the Hive documentation & tutorials, then you may understand why. Too much stuff there, a simple answer won't do.

Comment: You have not actually asked a question.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Their may be couple ways, here is one way

```
select order_date,  date_sub(concat(
(case 
WHEN MONTH(order_date) = '12'  THEN  concat( (YEAR(order_date) +1)  , '-01')
 WHEN MONTH(order_date) >= '10'  THEN  concat( (YEAR(order_date))  , '-',     (MONTH(order_date) +1))
  WHEN MONTH(order_date) >= '1'  THEN  concat( (YEAR(order_date))  , '-0', (MONTH(order_date) +1))
  ELSE 'XX' END)      ,'-01'  ) ,1)
```